# Pandas как декодировать unicode значения в столбце фрейма

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, decode

Имеется фрейм данных:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
data = {'фрукт': ['\\u0433\\u0440\\u0443\\u0448\\u0430','арбуз', '\\u0433\\u0440\\u0443\\u0448\\u0430', '\\u0432\\u0438\\u0448\\u043d\\u044f', '\\u0432\\u0438\\u0448\\u043d\\u044f', '\\u0433\\u0440\\u0443\\u0448\\u0430', '\\u0431\\u0430\\u043d\\u0430\\u043d'],
'страна': ['сша', np.nan, np.nan,'канада', 'португалия', np.nan, 'перу'],
'id': ['01','01', '011', '011', '6', '5', '5'],
'месяц': ['январь','январь', 'февраль', 'февраль', 'март', 'апрель', 'апрель']
}
dates = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['фрукт','страна', 'id', 'месяц'])
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Нужно декодировать unicode значения столбца "фрукт" в utf-8, так чтобы значения стали читаемыми. Как можно это сделать?

Ожидаемый результат:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы можете сделать подобным образом:

```
dates.loc[dates["фрукт"].str.contains(r"\\u"), "фрукт"] = dates.loc[dates["фрукт"].str.
                                                                    contains(r"\\u"), "фрукт"].str.decode("unicode-escape")
```

Но я бы советовал позаботиться об исправлении данных до добавления из в датафрейм.

Comment: +1 “Но я бы советовал позаботиться об исправлении данных до добавления из в датафрейм.”